# How do I change sound output from the green audio jack to the blue audio jack?

Tags: sound, alsa

Well i am new to linux, but i have a little problem.
My green audio jack died and i only have a blue and a pink audio jack wich both work under windows.
The pink jack works but I don't how to get the sound trough the blue jack.
I've tried Ubuntu and Kubuntu.
None of them has worked.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to reconfigure things using the HDA Analyzer : http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/HDA_Analyzer ; the interface is a bit raw, but I was able to use this tool to successfully diagnose a fault in the HDA codec drivers.

Answer (score 0):

> sudo alsamixer

I think M=mute/unmute
 < > keys = mute/unmute right left.
You wanna unmute the jack in question.

there also may be a "Headphone" button* you select.

Best to just mess around in the alsamixer